# Dynamically create objects and setting their attributes using suds lib in python

Tags: python, object, dynamic, suds

I'm using a raspberry to send some sensor data over to a SOAP webservice. RPi gets the data from the serial port. The format is 'DATE, VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3, VALUE4\r\n'. The webservice request looks like this

```
  <sensors>
    <Sensor>
      <SensorId>int</SensorId>
      <NodeId>int</NodeId>
      <SensorTypeId>int</SensorTypeId>
      <Value>double</Value>
      <Status>string</Status>
      <Date>dateTime</Date>
      <Deleted>boolean</Deleted>
      <Updated>boolean</Updated>
      <RemoteId>int</RemoteId>
      <DateOfLastUpdate>dateTime</DateOfLastUpdate>
      <UserId>int</UserId>
      <ErrorMessage>string</ErrorMessage>
    </Sensor>
    <Sensor>
      <SensorId>int</SensorId>
      <NodeId>int</NodeId>
      <SensorTypeId>int</SensorTypeId>
      <Value>double</Value>
      <Status>string</Status>
      <Date>dateTime</Date>
      <Deleted>boolean</Deleted>
      <Updated>boolean</Updated>
      <RemoteId>int</RemoteId>
      <DateOfLastUpdate>dateTime</DateOfLastUpdate>
      <UserId>int</UserId>
      <ErrorMessage>string</ErrorMessage>
    </Sensor>
  </sensors>
  <username>string</username>
  <password>string</password>
  <UniqueClientID>string</UniqueClientID>
  <project>string</project>
```

Each line I get from the serial port has 4 sensor values and the datetime these values were logged. So I need to create 4 objects with the SUDS library method client.factory.create() for each line I parse from the serial, add the values to each attribute and append() the objects to the Array of Sensor objects that the webservice accepts as its first parameter. The problem is I can't find a way to dynamically create the objects, enter the attributes' values, and append them to the big array. I'm going to parse probably 600lines from the serial port, so 4x600=2400 will need to be created. Hard-coding object names like this

```
while True:
serial_str = port.readline()
if serial_str:
    string_list = serial_str.split(',')
    date = 'T'.join( [ string_list[i] for i in [0, 1] ] )
    temperature = string_list[2]
    humidity = string_list[3]
    rain = string_list[4]
    wind = string_list[5].replace("\r\n","")
    Sensor_obj1 = client.factory.create('Sensor')
    Sensor_obj1.SensorId = -1
    Sensor_obj1.NodeId = 1
    Sensor_obj1.SensorTypeId = 2
    Sensor_obj1.Value = temperature
    Sensor_obj1.Status = ''
    Sensor_obj1.Date = date
    Sensor_obj1.Deleted = 0
    Sensor_obj1.Updated = 0
    Sensor_obj1.RemoteId = 0
    Sensor_obj1.DateOfLastUpdate = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')datetime.now()
    Sensor_obj1.UserId = 0
    Sensor_obj1.ErrorMessage = ''
    Sensor_list_obj.Sensor.append(Sensor_obj1)
    Sensor_obj2 = client.factory.create('Sensor')
    ...
```

would work if I only had 1 line to send, but even then its a bad programming style. I just got started with python 2.x, so I would appreciate if someone would point me to the right direction here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with the problem at hand, but I would guess that you can add more parameters to the call to client.factory.create('Sensor') call. Does it accept, **kwargs, so that you can call:

```
client.factory.create('Sensor', SensorID=-1, NodeId=1, ...)
```

If not, you can always abstract the initialization by:

- Creating a function that does all the asignments and hides away the 'gory' details. This is elegant enough, and probably you shouldn't try anything more advanced if you have just started programming in python.
- Create a class Sensor, that inherits from the one of suds. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about the class of objects 'client.factory.create'.

Also, I think I would create a list of sensors (or dictionary, if that makes sense in your code), so that you append all the sensors to that structure, otherwise your program will be impossible to use if you have three or five sensors instead of 4.